# how to filterdate if it contains time

Tags: php, mysql

i want filter between dates only by selection date. my db has entered dates records with different times values. but i want filter only date.

here is my code

```
<?php  
 //filter.php  
 if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");  
      $output = '';  
      $query = "  

      SELECT 
      CreatedDate,
      COUNT(`Ticket`) AS Tickets,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Closed'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Closed 
      
      FROM Dashboarddetails

 
      WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."'
      GROUP BY CreatedDate
ORDER BY CreatedDate
";
```

please find the picture this is the result im getting current code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the DATE() function
and you should avoid the use of php var in  sql code for  prevent sqlinjection for this take a look apt prepatred statemente and binding param for you db driver

Based on fact you are using msqli and not PDO  the you could use

```
if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  
 {  

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");  
    $output = '';  
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("CreatedDate,
        COUNT(`Ticket`) AS Tickets,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Closed'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Closed 
        FROM Dashboarddetails"; 
        WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN DATE(?) AND DATE(?)
        GROUP BY CreatedDate
        ORDER BY CreatedDate");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
     while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     ....
    }

   .....
```

Anyway be sure taht you dates in POST are date sting  in canonical format  and the date() part of the two date a valid  date range  (if the two date you pass are fro the same dayyour between clause don't work   )

Comment: `<?php  
 //filter.php  
 if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  
 ` im using date filter code, so how to use this one

Comment: answer  upodate  with suggestion

Comment: can u please tellme how can i use this code full in my db, im really new to use with PDo

Comment: Which db driver you are really using ??? ..  you should update your question and add the pho code where you invoke the sql code  ..

Comment: I think the `DATE()` should be around `CreatedDate` because the parameters from `POST` are already dates

Comment: @moseleyi Note that functions cannot use indexes, so this might not be the best idea